# How to add a search box on a leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want to use a leaflet map to be a page's background. And this page has a search function, but this search box is not used to search this map. So my question is how to add a search box on a leaflet map?

Do you have any other solution to use a map to be the background?
like this page: http://directory.spatineo.com/

Comment: I want to use a leaflet map to be a page's background.And this page has a  search function,but this search box is not use to search this map. So my question is how to add a search box on a leaflet map?

Do you have any other solution to use a map to be the background.

Comment: Have you looked into custom controls with L.Control?(http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control)

Comment: Yes，L.Control' controls are all about to control the map,but not has the search box control..

Comment: @Anchor, add any html element on your page and set its position as `absolute` and set `top` and `left/right` position, this way you can add search box on map

Comment: Yes, L.Control is the boilerplate for leaflet controls,they are extremely flexible, you add whatever elements you need, but it's up to you to add the search functionality...just add an input field and add listeners as needed.

Answer (score 16):

There are many solutions available to adding a search control to a leaflet map. Some are listed on the [Leaflet Plugin page under Search and Popups](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#search--popups). The search control needs some data to conduct the search, so you should have access to some data on your map. You can host the data on your map or connect to some remote data source(s).

**Search Local Level Locations:**

If your search criteria is to retrieve data you hosted on the map, then I recommend the [Leaflet Search plugin maintained by Stefano Cudini](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) See a working example on [this link](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/simple.html).

Read more at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130623/adding-a-search-box-to-a-leaflet-js-example

**Search Global Level Locations:**

If you want the search criteria to search for random places around the world (that is the database isn't in your app), then use a custom solution provided by a company like [ESRI Leaflet project](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder). See working example this codepen page: '[leaflet map with place search](https://codepen.io/exomark/pen/dafBD)'.

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>LeafletJS with Search Box</title>

   <!-- CSS and JS files for Search Box -->
    <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">

</head>
<body>

        <div id="map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // This setup the leafmap object by linking the map() method to the map id (in <div> html element)
        var map = L.map('map', {
              center: [51.517327, -0.120005],
              zoom: 1.5,
              // minZoom: 1.5,
             //  maxZoom: 1.5
            });

        // Start adding controls as follow... L.controlName().addTo(map);

        // Control 1: This add the OpenStreetMap background tile
            L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
              attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);


        // Control 2: This add a scale to the map
            L.control.scale().addTo(map);

        // Control 3: This add a Search bar
            var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);

            var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

              searchControl.on('results', function(data){
                results.clearLayers();
                for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
                }
              });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does including the Geocoding by Esri suffice in meeting license conditions? Or will there need to be more lengthy accreditation if this is going to be for an web app? -I noticed that Esri also sites data providers, or is that only for map tiling?

Answer (score 2):

This solution works with last versions of [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) and [geosearch](https://github.com/8to5Developer/leaflet-custom-searchbox/blob/master/src/leaflet.customsearchbox.js). First load scripts from unpkg.com (the order is important here).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.1.0/dist/geosearch.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.1.0/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [36.979120, -121.899390],
      zoom: 5
    }); //Creates a leaflet map centered at center [latitude, longitude] coordinates.

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }).addTo(map); //Creates the attribution box at the top bottom right of map.

    const provider = new window.GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider();
    const search = new GeoSearch.GeoSearchControl({
      provider: provider,
      style: 'bar',
      updateMap: true,
      autoClose: true,
    }); // Include the search box with usefull params. Autoclose and updateMap in my case. Provider is a compulsory parameter.

    L.marker([51.0, -0.09]).addTo(map).bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.'); //Creates a marker at [latitude, longitude] coordinates.
  });
</script>

<div id="map"></div> // Creates the wrapper cotaining the map
```

Comment: You may want to add explain.

Comment: Explained atline. Thank you.

Comment: It seems you missed ```map.addControl(search); ```