# How to style an embedded map on an HTML-File?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have the following HTML file, in which I embedded an openstreetmap with a search bar using instructions at [How to add a search box on a leaflet map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37189484/how-to-add-a-search-box-on-a-leaflet-map). Now I am trying to style it a bit. I would like to place the searchbar below the map and also fixate it so that it doesn't disappear but is visible at all times. I would also like to work on the height and width of the search bar.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de">

<head>
 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
 <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.0.8"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">

    

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="Anzeige%20erstellen-Dateien/index111.css">

  
</head>

<body class="without-navs show-help">

                                                        <div id="mapid" style="width: 1287px; height: 300px; position: relative; outline: none;" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom" tabindex="0"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"><div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;"><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4093/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4094/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4093/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4094/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4092/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4095/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4092/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4095/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"><img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png" class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" alt="" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px);"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480" style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);"><g><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M141.20355555554852,171.94704600190744a42,42 0 1,0 84,0 a42,42 0 1,0 -84,0 "></path><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M358 163L474 219L550 153z"></path></g></svg></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px); z-index: 247;"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"><div class="leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated" style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(301px, 213px, 0px); bottom: -7px; left: -57px;"><div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper"><div class="leaflet-popup-content" style="width: 74px;"><b>Hello world!</b><br>I am a popup.</div></div><div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container"><div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div></div><a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="#close">×</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(1.04805e+06px, 697379px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map data © <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"><div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;"><div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated" style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img alt="" role="presentation" src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw" class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded" style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;"></div></div></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"><img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png" class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" alt="" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(-78224px, 9814px, 0px);"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480" style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);"><g><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path></g></svg></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(-78224px, 9814px, 0px); z-index: 9814;"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(1.12658e+06px, 687812px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map data © <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a></div></div></div></div>
                            <script>

 var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([52.487013959237444,13.424820899963377], 15);

 L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  maxZoom: 18,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
   '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
   'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
 }).addTo(mymap);                                       

                                var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(mymap);

            var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(mymap);

              searchControl.on('results', function(data){
                results.clearLayers();
                for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                  results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));
                }
              });

var popup = L.popup();
        var point=[52.515803012883595,13.38958740234375];
                                        var marker= L.marker(point).addTo(mymap);

 function onMapClick(e) {
  popup
   .setLatLng(e.latlng)
   .setContent("Sie haben geklickt auf: " + e.latlng.toString())
   .openOn(mymap);
 }  
 mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

</script>                               
</body>

</html>
```

I'm very limited in my knowledge of html/css/javascript. If I'm not wrong, the part in the above html-code that deals with the search bar is this:

```
    <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480" style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);"><g><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path><path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path></g></svg></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(-78224px, 9814px, 0px); z-index: 9814;"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated" style="transform: translate3d(1.12658e+06px, 687812px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div></div><div class="leaflet-control-container"><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left"><div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div></div><div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div><div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right"><div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Map data © <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a></div></div></div></div>
```

I've tried to change the values of various elements in this section, like width , margin-left, padding etc. But, the code did not respond to the changes I made. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you want to place the search bar outside of the map container? Did I get this correctly?

Comment: @kboul   without wanting to sound too dumb: I  think that's what I want. Or if that's not possible, then at least at the bottom of the map, fixated and readjusted size.

Comment: I am not sure whether you can do that. Usually this plugin is designed to be on top of the map. Check [this](https://community.esri.com/thread/210038-place-esri-leaflet-geocoding-control-outside-of-the-map) and [this](https://github.com/jgravois/bootstrap-geocoder)